# Displaying all the facets using InstantSearch

Tags: laravel, vue.js, algolia, laravel-scout, instantsearch.js

So I am trying to change the default setting to getting facets from Algolia which is 10. I'm using `Laravel` with `Laravel-Scout` and `Vue.js` with `InstantSearch.js`. Since the Vue provides me with a template of displaying the facets I use:

```
    <ais-refinement-list attribute-name="actors.name">
         <h3 slot="header">Actors</h3>
    </ais-refinement-list>
```

This way I only get 10. I tried using the `Laravel-scout-settings`. Downloaded the settings and tried adding `maxFacetsHits : 30`, when I pushed them back, no changes took place. Is it possible to actually edit these setting using their template wrapper or I'm going to have to use the `InstantSearch` js way of adding all the widgets and settings through a js file.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: In summary my question was how to display more of the Facets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the option I was looking for and it's `limit`.

My code looks as following now:

```
    <ais-refinement-list limit=20 attribute-name="actors.name">
        <h3 slot="header">Actors</h3>
    </ais-refinement-list>
```

This will actually display 20 of my facets instead of 10.
I'm sorry if my request above didn't clearly specify what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter [`maxFacetHits`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/maxFacetHits/) is only used when your perform a [`searchForFacetValues`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search-for-facet-values/). In your case you want to update the [`maxValuesPerFacet`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/maxValuesPerFacet). It will update the number of values retrieved for each facet.

Comment: Actually I needed the `maxFacetHits` because the `maxValuesPerFacet` give values per facet as stated and I wanted to increase the number of facets shown. I found the answer myself I will post it down.